# What is enough to convey a Show / Hide link information?

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, labels

Usage context: I have a voucher, which has conditions of use. 
I can see conditions of use in a collapsible panel.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjK4xv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Should I use the right proposition  or the left proposition?

Is there any good reason to chose one or the other?

Comment: Collapse is a pattern alright, but in my view is somewhat overused. If you chart the use case and conduct cognitive analysis, you may find that *progressive disclosure* or *modal* are better solutions. In the case of the former there is only 'show conditions control', which once clicked is replaced with the content (exactly like the comment I'm typing now, which has no 'cancel' option). You can argue that conditions are distinct - the user doesn't need them along with the rest of the page, so a modal might be a better choice here.

Comment: Yes but I can have multiple vouchers with multiple conditions and if conditions take too much space I cannot compare vouchers between them anymore, that's why user can show/hide them at will.
Modal dialog would break the flow, this is not what I want

Answer (score 4):

[Buttons should say what they do](http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-your-form-buttons-should-never-say-submit/), or actionable links in your case.

"Conditions" doesn't mean squat. "Show Conditions" tells me exactly what action I'm about to take.

Would most users figure out "Conditions"? Probably. Would more users figure out "Show/Hide Conditions"? Yes.

Should you hide important legal information? No. But that's a different question.

Comment: I wanted an answer more specific, maybe backed up with data?

While I agree with your opinion and explanation about the clear labels, the question is more about: Is the triangle icon + the hyperlink + the label (without the 'show') explicit enough for Most + More people to understand ?

Other thing: maybe 'show conditions' label is more explicit but 'conditions' label is more concise. So I still don't know if one solution is way better than the other ...

Comment: We can't do your user research for you. Is the triangle + others explicit enough? We don't know. Your site might be full of triangles, might be blue heavy, your target users might have a triangle-phobia. All of that would certainly affect the answer. In *general* will most people understand either pattern? Yes. Will explicitly saying show/hide improve this? Yes. Will "conditions" work better? We have no idea. You need to put it in front of target users and test it.